# Import multiple xyz files and rasterize them

Tags: qgis, rasterization, xyz

How can I load multiple XYZ files in QGIS?

I want to load about 100 files to create from each one a raster so we can overlay our network on them.

Manually it's too much work. I tried to create a model where I load all the files with the same parameters and then rasterize them. My thought is to run the model as a batch when its finished.

I didn't find an algorithm that loads all the xyz files with the same parameters. My file format is custom delimiters (space) and the point coordinates are the fields containing x , y values. If do this over layer > add a delimited layer it's fine. But I want to import all the files automatically from my folder without setting every time manually the parameters. The second step is to rasterize this layers then one by one. I thought the model builder was a good idea. Maybe there is another way for my doing.

How can I do this an easy way?

Comment: Create a model and run it in batch. That is the easy way. Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: how can i do this. i didnt find a algorithm that loads all the xyz files with the same parameters. for example my file format is custom delimiters (space) and the point coocrdinates are the fields containing x , y values. if do this over layer< add a delimited layer its fine. but i want to import all the files automatically from my folder without setting every time manually the parameters. the second step is to rasterize this layers then one by one. I thougt the model builder was a good idea. maybe there is another way for my doing.

Comment: Look for tutorials on the graphical modeler like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih6MkK58mog). You can then string algorithms one after another and easily iterate and batch execute.

Answer (score 1):

According to the first part of your question (batch import of xyz files) :

I adapted [Germán Carrillo's code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146578/how-to-create-multiple-qgis-layers-from-multiple-text-files/336401#336401) to import xyz files in QGIS 3 (I use it to import river cross sections).

As the fields in my cross profile tables are separated by multiple spaces, what results in adding several empty columns if I use " " as decimal separator, I added a piece of code to replace the spaces by a comma (consecutive spaces are replaced by one coma). For the rest I used the same procedure as described in Germán Carrillo's post to import the cross profiles.

```
import os.path, glob
layers=[]
profile = 0
directory = 'X:/My/Working/Directory/' # Change this base path
for file in glob.glob(directory+'*.xyz'): 
  f = open(file, 'r')
  lines = f.readlines()
  f.close()
  new_file = directory+'PT_'+str(profile+1)+'.xyz'
  fw = open(new_file, 'w')
  for l in lines:
     fw.write(re.sub("\s+", ",", l.strip())+'\n')
  fw.close()
  uri = "file:///" + new_file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&useHeader=no&crs=epsg:3943" % (",", "field_2","field_3")
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(0,'id')
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'X')
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(2,'Y')
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(3,'Y')
  layers.append(vlayer)
  profile +=1

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

As you can see in QGIS 3:

- *addAttributeAlias* has been replaced by *setFieldAlias*
- *QgsMapLayerRegistry* has been replaced by *QgsProject*

Below the original structure of my cross profiles:

```
1  1950459.685  2218176.491    37.574     0
2  1950468.259  2218173.250    37.466     0
3  1950471.806  2218171.910    37.466     0
4  1950474.013  2218171.076    35.000     0
5  1950477.754  2218169.662    35.000     0
6  1950480.095  2218168.777    36.465     0
7  1950483.372  2218167.539    36.465     0
8  1950495.173  2218163.079    37.214     0
```

And the resulting table after applying the *strip function* on each line.

```
1,1950459.685,2218176.491,37.574,0
2,1950468.259,2218173.250,37.466,0
3,1950471.806,2218171.910,37.466,0
4,1950474.013,2218171.076,35.000,0
5,1950477.754,2218169.662,35.000,0
6,1950480.095,2218168.777,36.465,0
7,1950483.372,2218167.539,36.465,0
8,1950495.173,2218163.079,37.214,0
```

There are probably some improvements that can be done, but at least it works for me.