# Bulk importing delimited text layers in QGIS Python fail

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I've got a bunch of CSV files to add as text delimited layers to my GIS project. They all have identical formats in the UK EPSG:27700 CRS with a column marked "eastings"(column 0) and another marked "northings" (column 1).

The csv looks a bit like this:

```
Eastings,Northings,GridRef,Climate,AT,ATA,ATDefault,CT,DAMS,DAMSA,DAMSAdj,MD,SMR,SNR,SiteClass,SMRA,SNRA,SMRN,SNRN,SMRAN,SNRAN,SMRD,SNRD,SNRB,SNRF,SNRG,SMRAspect,Brash,Drainage,Fertiliser,BrashApplied,DrainageApplied,FertiliserApplied,DamsModified,Filter,species,commonname,latinname,modelVersion,modelConfidence,threat,yc,suit,tsuit,limitingFactor,atR,ctR,damsR,mdR,smrR,snrR
363537,473249,SD635732,Medium-High 2050 (A1b/3q0) AWC method,2351,0,2351,7,11,0,11,166,Moderately dry,Poor,Warm - Sheltered - Moist,Moderately dry,Poor,7,2,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,No brash present,No drainage installed,No fertiliser,0,0,0,0,All species,AH,Ash,Fraxinus excelsior,3.0,A,Chalara,0,0.0,0.0,SMR,0.99,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.0,0.0
363537,472249,SD635722,Medium-High 2050 (A1b/3q0) AWC method,2366,0,2366,7,9,0,9,168,Moderately dry,Poor,Warm - Sheltered - Moist,Moderately dry,Poor,7,2,7,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,No brash present,No drainage installed,No fertiliser,0,0,0,0,All species,AH,Ash,Fraxinus excelsior,3.0,A,Chalara,0,0.0,0.0,SMR,0.98,1.0,1.0,0.89,0.0,0.0
363537,471249,SD635712,Medium-High 2050 (A1b/3q0) AWC method,2316,0,2316,7,11,0,11,163,Very moist,Medium,Warm - Sheltered - Moist,Very moist,Medium,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,No brash present,No drainage installed,No fertiliser,0,0,0,0,All species,AH,Ash,Fraxinus excelsior,3.0,A,Chalara,8,0.65,0.65,SNR,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.93,0.76,0.65
363537,470249,SD635702,Medium-High 2050 (A1b/3q0) AWC method,2291,0,2291,7,12,0,12,160,Very moist,Medium,Warm - Sheltered - Moist,Very moist,Medium,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,No brash present,No drainage installed,No fertiliser,0,0,0,0,All species,AH,Ash,Fraxinus excelsior,3.0,A,Chalara,8,0.65,0.65,SNR,1.0,1.0,0.99,0.95,0.76,0.65
363537,469249,SD635692,Medium-High 2050 (A1b/3q0) AWC method,2326,0,2326,7,12,0,12,164,Very moist,Medium,Warm - Sheltered - Moist,Very moist,Medium,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,No brash present,No drainage installed,No fertiliser,0,0,0,0,All species,AH,Ash,Fraxinus excelsior,3.0,A,Chalara,8,0.65,0.65,SNR,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.92,0.76,0.65
```

I have tried importing them using the code listed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/310415/157523), using the editor box of the Python window:

```
import os.path, glob
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
layers=[]

for file in glob.glob('C:/pathname/*.csv'): 
      uri = "file:///" + file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&useHeader=no&crs=epsg:27700" % (",","Eastings","Northings") #(Delimeter, XField, YField) #1st column in file is column 1
      vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
      vlayer.setFieldAlias(0,'X') #these order of columns go: 0, 1, 2 etc
      vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'Y')
      layers.append(vlayer)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

but... Literally nothing happens when I run the code.

If I try adding the code to a new script in the toolbox, I get an error `Seems there is no valid script in the file.`

Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .csv files have headers. In uri line change useHeader=no to useHeader=yes.
Corrected code (only change as mentioned above):

```
import os.path, glob
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
layers=[]

for file in glob.glob('C:/pathname/*.csv'): 
      uri = "file:///" + file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&useHeader=yes&crs=epsg:27700" % (",","Eastings","Northings") #(Delimeter, XField, YField) #1st column in file is column 1
      vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
      vlayer.setFieldAlias(0,'X') #these order of columns go: 0, 1, 2 etc
      vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'Y')
      layers.append(vlayer)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

Comment: Thanks @Szym the code runs, but I'm still not getting any of the layers appearing on my project though?

Comment: I tested it on QGIS 3.10. What is your version? What I did: 1) I took your csv fragment and saved as 2 .csv files. Both of them were added to my map, even though my CRS is WGS84

Comment: OK. That could be sorcery... I've just closed QGis and reopened it, and now it's working. No idea. Thanks for the support!