# Importing multiple txt files using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, batch, text, syntaxerror

I'm using QGIS v3.26, and cannot seem to get code referenced from another Q&A to work. This is the previous Q&A on this topic that I was looking at: [How to create multiple QGIS layers from multiple text files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146578/how-to-create-multiple-qgis-layers-from-multiple-text-files)

The files I'm attempting to import are from the EDGAR database showing spatial emission measurements in .txt files. They have three headers; when I manually import a layer using the gui in QGIS I have to select "Number of header lines to discard: 2" under the Record and Field Options tab. The third header has the column names.

```
import os.path, glob
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
layers=[]
for file in glob.glob('/home/Documents/*.txt'): # Change this base path
  uri = "file:///" + file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&useHeader=yes&crs=epsg:4326" % (";", "lat","lon")
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(0,'Y')
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'X')
  layers.append(vlayer)
  
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

If I run this code all I get is "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: can you upload a sample dataset to pastebin?

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/CKWikxrR

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `skipLines=2`. The most easy way to find out how the `uri` should look like is to load one example manually and than look into the `Information` section of the loaded layer. There you will find the `Source` with all the parameters you need.

This worked for me:

```py
import os.path, glob
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
layers=[]
for file in glob.glob(r'/tmp/*.txt'): # Change this base path
  uri = "file:///" + file + "?type=csv&delimiter=;&skipLines=2&detectTypes=yes&xField=lon&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no"
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(0,'Y')
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'X')
  layers.append(vlayer)
  
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```